# Spring Eureka on Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, netflix-eureka, openshift-origin

I have two simple Springboot microservice which connect with each other using Spring Eureka.

Steps -

1. First I run Eureka server.
2. Then I run both the microservices.
3. So both microservices register & discovery from Eureka server.

I want to achieve the same in Openshift v3. I know Openshift uses Kubernates Service for achieving load-balancing & pod-discovery. But can I use Eureka server in Openshift?

In Openshift I have 3 pods..

1. 1 pod for eureka and 2 pods for microservices.
2. Both microservices register with eureka.
3. But in Eureka, it is registering as microservice's pod IP:PORT.
4. So when discovering the microservice tries to make the call to POD
   IP & fails.

Generally, to access POD IP we need to invoke service layer in Openshift.
So how can I make eureka server register server layer IP:PORT instead of POD's IP:PORT

Comment: Q: Do the both microservices are deployed out of openshift?

Comment: Microservices are deployed inside Openshift. 
1) I have 3 pods, 1 for eureka and 2 for microservices.
2) Both microservices register with eureka.
3) But in Eureka, it is registering as microservice's pod IP:PORT.

Comment: eureka.instance.hostname  =  should be use service name. it should be found in your openshift console.

Answer (score 2):

for Spring Cloud Eureka Server project:application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: server.eureka.svc   # it should be service url in openshift cluster.
  client:
    fetch-registry: false 
    register-with-eureka: false 
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

For Spring Cloud Eureka Client project: application.yml

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://server.eureka.svc8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
```

Comment: @Maks could you please provide more infos to inspect the reason.

Comment: I don't know how to do it( I set hostname from openshift and change eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone accordingly.

Comment: Maybe, I will try this one later: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes. Right now, I am not using registry when I deploy to openshift(